# Postgres: Get which part is a record within a set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to obtain or calculate the information of each record within a set (installment and partial value), I explain below with an example:

```
| pay        |  date       | value |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----:|
| 910006603  | 2017-04-19  | 30    |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-21  | 30    |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-23  | 30    |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-25  | 30    |  
| 910006604  | 2017-04-14  | 45    | 
| 910006604  | 2017-04-18  | 45    |
```

With this information I must add two other columns, indicating the installment and the partial value of it, so that it results:

```
| pay        |  date       | value | insta | partial|
|:-----------|------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|
| 910006603  | 2017-04-19  | 30    | 1     | 30     |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-21  | 30    | 2     | 60     |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-23  | 30    | 3     | 90     |
| 910006603  | 2017-04-25  | 30    | 4     | 120    |

| 910006604  | 2017-04-14  | 45    | 1     | 45     | 
| 910006604  | 2017-04-18  | 45    | 2     | 90     |
```

I hope to be explicit enough, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it by using ROW_NUMBER() and SUM() [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-window.html).

> ```
> create table payments(pay int, dt date, value int);
> insert into payments values
> (910006603, '2017-04-19', 30),
> (910006603, '2017-04-21', 30),
> (910006603, '2017-04-23', 30),
> (910006603, '2017-04-25', 30),
> (910006604, '2017-04-14', 45),
> (910006604, '2017-04-18', 45);
> ```

> ```
> select pay, 
>        dt as date, 
>        value, 
>        row_number() over (partition by pay order by dt) as insta,
>        sum(value) over (partition by pay order by dt) as partial
> from   payments;
> ```
>
> ```
>       pay | date       | value | insta | partial
> --------: | :--------- | ----: | ----: | ------:
> 910006603 | 2017-04-19 |    30 |     1 |      30
> 910006603 | 2017-04-21 |    30 |     2 |      60
> 910006603 | 2017-04-23 |    30 |     3 |      90
> 910006603 | 2017-04-25 |    30 |     4 |     120
> 910006604 | 2017-04-14 |    45 |     1 |      45
> 910006604 | 2017-04-18 |    45 |     2 |      90
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f2ee2f46063ec9c7e8fad25042a68813)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know in case of any queries.

```
select pay, date, value,
       (select sum(value) from t t2 where t2.pay = t.pay and t2.date <= t.date) as partial,
       (select count(*) from t t3 where t3.pay = t.pay and t3.date <= t.date) as insta
from table t;
```